# Corosync with Pacemaker Resource explanation

Tags: linux, centos6, pacemaker, corosync

I have the following resource:

```
primitive WowzaMediaServer lsb:WowzaMediaServer \
        op monitor interval="30s" timeout="60" \
        op start interval="0" timeout="60" \
        op stop interval="0"
```

I would like to understand what does "monitor Interval" and "timeout" mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means:

Monitor (i.e. **check its status**) the lsb service WowzaMediaServer every 30 seconds and timeout after 60 seconds.

http://clusterlabs.org/doc/en-US/Pacemaker/1.1-crmsh/html/Clusters_from_Scratch/_adding_a_resource.html